# How did "print i[-1]" wrap from z to a in this caesar cipher code?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, caesar-cipher

Like the title says, why do we use "print i[-1]" in this code?

```
def caesar_cipher (string, number)
  string.scan (/./) do |i|
    if ("a".."z").include? (i.downcase) # Identify letters only. 
      number.times {i = i.next}
    end
    print i[-1] # Wrap from z to a. 
  end
end

caesar_cipher("Testing abzxc.", 5)
```

I understand all of the code except that particular line. How was ruby able to wrap Z to A? I mean look at this code:

```
test1 = "z"
puts test1[-1]
# result is Z not A
```

I was expecting the result to be A but the result is Z. Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is `"z"`, the `caesar_cipher("z", 5)` will call the `i = i.next` 5 times, which moves `i` to the 5th element followed.

```
i = "z"
i = i.next    # aa
i = i.next    # ab
i = i.next    # ac
i = i.next    # ad
i = i.next    # ae
```

Now, the `i[-1]` will extract the last character from the result, and discard the leading carry `a`.

Comment: this was exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

See [String#`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

`test1[-1]` returns the last letter of the string. Since the last letter of string `"z"` is `"z"`, it returns it.

Comment: yeah but so does i[-1].  Except that it went straight to A, I was wondering why test1 will not do the same

Comment: @jibzoiderz I explained exactly what happens with `test1[-1]`.

Comment: yeah you are correct. But what I was looking for was @Arie Shaw 's explanation. It was my fault for not asking properly